# "pages_show_list" permission not listed in "add items to this submission" for Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook web application, that was just reviewed and approved by Facebook, so it's generally public. The application needs to be able to get the data about user accounts, so it needs either `manage_pages` or `pages_show_list` permission from user to work correctly. I don't need to manage user pages, only list them, so I want to request for `pages_show_list` login permission. However, when I go to the app settings and then "status & review" -> "items in review" and I click "add items to this submission" I see list of items, but there's no `pages_show_list` under "login permissions section".

How do I request for that item?

As an aside note: I know that Facebook added this permission recently, in Graph API v2.5, can that be a problem? My app used to make requests for the earlier versions of the API, but there's no general switch to choose what version to use (is it?), so I assume that Facebook doesn't limit this functionality for me because of that.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I got the answer from Facebook Support. It states that this permission doesn't require any additional review and you can just use it.

Comment: Does not work for me; /me/accounts returns an empty JSON array. If I try in Graph API Explorer with a freshly created access token, it works. BTW, the pages_show_list permission is ticked and grayed out in the permissions list when I click on Get Token. Does it work for you?

Comment: Got it: I had to add `pages_show_list` to the scope parameter during login of the app. I confused the scope parameter with the lost of permissions in the app configuration.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier, wasn't able to. But good you were able to make it work anyway.

Comment: Just to be clear for others - I'm pretty sure we still need to *request* the permission upon connection.  Our apps just don't need to go through an additional round of review for this permission.

Comment: Hi there, are you by chance able to confirm that this is still the case?  The page for this permission clearly states it requires app review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_show_list/  Additionally, finding any sort of actual human support is beyond impossible.  I am curious how you were able to contact their support.

Comment: @Mike-E hi, sorry for late answer. Well it's been 7 years so I have no idea, but AFAIR the app itself needs to be reviewed, but it doesn't need to be additionally reviewed for this specific permission. Also about Facebook support, I think I asked on their developer help forum or smth, but again it's been 7 years.

Comment: I appreciate you checking in no matter the delay @KubaJagoda.  For the edification for anyone else seeing this, Facebook is incredibly undersupported, and the user interface for the entire permission structure is beyond confusing.  I required no app review for this permission despite the documentation's insistence.  In my case, I had a well-hidden data review alert that I had to coax/prod from their broken software to complete and I was able to use my application as desired, without again any app review. ‍♂️

Comment: If you'd like to see pure dysfunction, check out the Facebook Developer bug reporting system.  After nearly five weeks of trying to track down an issue, it appears now that `pages_show_list` is only now available in their business applications.  So you must be a verified business with an app to use this https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1060918257954718/