# Permissions: manage_pages vs pages_show_list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using v2.5 of the Facebook Graph API.

What's the difference between `manage_pages` and `pages_show_list` permissions?

From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages) it seems that you need `manage_pages` to get a page access token. But I tried and I was able to get it with just the `pages_show_list` permission.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked what this page access token allows you to do? It should only allow you to read information about the page – but not _change_ any settings, as a page token acquired using `manage_pages` would do.

Answer (score 2):

The docs are vague und not complete on this subject. Facebook says they grant `pages_show_list` to all apps (I can't confirm this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336737/pages-show-list-permission-not-listed-in-add-items-to-this-submission-for-fa)), while `manage_pages` requires review by Facebook.

One import difference is the way the app is presented to the user. If you request `manage_pages`, the user will be told that your app wants to manage his/her pages before the user approves.

Besides that, the only difference I found in the docs is the fact that `manage_pages` combined with `publish_pages`allows apps to, well, publish pages.

Answer (score 0):

`pages_show_list` simply allows you to receive a list of the pages that the requesting user is an admin of.