# Facebook app review - To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I want to submit my Facebook app and Page Public Content Access permission for review.
The app uses API v.3.0. To get my permission request reviewed, I need to provide "Details for Page Public Content Access" and, particularly, to create a screencast which demonstrates

1. How a person logs in with Facebook
2. How a person sees this feature used in your app

My app is in development mode. When I use the app to request posts of my own page via `[https:]//graph.facebook.com/mypageID/posts?access_token=myappID|myappSecret` 
to make the screencast, API returns **Exception : (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access**, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook`.

So I cannot demonstrate how the app works to get it reviewed. Basically a deadlock. Is there some bug in FB API ? How can I get this situation fixed?

Comment: Use your user token, or a page token …?

Comment: User token, because I need to demonstrate how it works to get permission request reviewed.

Comment: I meant use the user token for your API request.

Comment: That is the point. When I use user token for API request to display my own page's content, FB returns that error.

Comment: You need to ask for `pages_show_list` permission at least for that to work (either that, or manage_pages), otherwise the API doesn’t know that you have admin access to the page to begin with.

Comment: thanks, it worked. `pages_show_list` is needed. To get it, I used
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336737/pages-show-list-permission-not-listed-in-add-items-to-this-submission-for-fa#comment57711928_34354531

Comment: did you get the public page content access permission? Was using page_show_list permission sufficient?

Comment: no, page_show_list permission was not sufficient. And we did not get public page content access permission twice. So we will try again.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not a bug. If your app is not in the public mode, you can access the public content of facebook pages which you or the facebook accounts you added to the Roles are admin of. As mentioned in Facebook Documentation

> While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app.

You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

So you basically need to create your own facebook page and use it in the screencast.
PS: make sure your app is in the development mode